# Truth value of a mathematical statement about circles?

Tags: logic, circles, quantifiers

Let $A$ be the set of circles in the plane with center $(0,0)$ and let $B$ be the set of circles in the plane with center $(-2,3)$.

Furthermore, let $P(C_1,C_2)\colon C_1$ and $C_2$ have exactly one point in common, be an open sentence where the domain of $C_1$ is $A$ and the domain of $C_2$ is $B$.

How do I find the truth value of the above statement: There exists a circle with center $(0,0)$ in $A$ such that for all circles with center $(-2,3), C_1$ and $C_2$ have exactly one point in common?

Comment: if such a circle can exist then either it is a point (zero radius) through which every circle from $B$ has to pass or it will be tangent to every circle with center $(-2,3)$. Neither of which can occur (think in terms of geometry).